# I have made an array inside of a parameter and I do not know how to call a method on BlueJ

Tags: java, methods, bluej

[Image of my method call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajnNt.png)

I cannot figure out what to enter into my method call box.
If someone could help directing me to the answer I would appreciate that.

I tried an `int[][]` array as a parameter, but I don't know what to do next...

```
public void generateGrades(int tray[][]) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            if(tray[i][j] < 25) 
            {
                lowGrade.add(tray[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                highGrade.add(tray[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("lowGrade:");
        sortingLithium(lowGrade);
        System.out.println("highGrade");
        sortingLithium(highGrade);
    }
}
```

These are my "High grade" values:

```
32 33 38 40
```

These are my "Low grade" values:

```
2  4  11 12 13 15 16 25
```

Comment: How are we meant to help you when you give no indication of what your code is even supposed to do? What are you trying to achieve here? What's wrong with what you're already doing? What is "array inside of a parameter" supposed to mean?

Comment: My code should print out what you see above but I can't call the method. I meant Array as a parameter

Comment: I tried to improve your question by reformatting it. Still, there is a lot to do before this will be be an answerable question (no offense).

Comment: none taken I get why it's hard to understand, I am trying to method call using a parameter on BlueJ but I don't know how to method call, everything I enter is coming out with an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can call as:

`int[][] trArray = new int[2][2];
 generateGrades(trArray);`

Your method will look like this:

`public void generateGrades(int[][] tray)`